# How to classify a document by image?

Tags: python, similar-documents

I need an opens source solution to classify a document. I do not want to use NLP i need only to check the look and feel.

I tried [OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/master/df/dfb/group__imgproc__object.html). I have a template and i need to match it.

```
import cv2

template = cv2.imread(template_file,0)
template = cv2.normalize(template, None, alpha=0, beta=1, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_32F)

 method = ['cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED'] 

 img = img2.copy()
 method = eval(meth)
 # Apply template Matching
 res = cv2.matchTemplate(img,template,method)

 min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)
 if (max_val > threshold):
    print('match OK')
```

this method doesn't seems so robust and I get a lot of false positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at Siamese CNNs depending on the size of your dataset. A good introduction can be found [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/one-shot-learning-with-siamese-networks-using-keras-17f34e75bb3d).

Comment: using CNN is the best solution, I think you can get an eye also there https://github.com/nagelflorian/document-classification